# Custom dialog box control in c#

Tags: c#, dialog, controls

I have a question I hope some of you might be able to answer, I haven't found any ways to do this on google or here.

What I want:
- A custom control that functions just like an input box. (But it has to be a winform control that can be added to a form. Not a form.)
- It has to be able to grab the value from its text box and send it to the parent in the function it was called in.

Here is how I want to call it:

```
string str = MyBox.GetString("control title");
```

Can anyone help?

I don't know if this is event possible in c#. I couldn't figure it out, but if anyone can please answer!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "input box"? Do you mena textbox or something else? EDIT: Sorrym I realize now that you mean a simple dialog box with a label, a textbox, a title and an OK and cancel button.

Comment: Why do you think it should work this way. Why do you not want to use a reference to the specific text box and access the `Text` property?

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this

```
public partial class MyBox : Form
{
    public MyBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ResultText { get; set; }

    public static string GetString(string title)
    {
        var box = new MyBox {Text = title};

        if (box.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return box.ResultText;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResultText = txtUserInput.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

where MyBox would be a Form with TextBox - `txtUserInput` and an okay button linked to the `okButton_Click` event.

And you can make calls from other forms like this:

```
string userInput = MyBox.GetString("Title for MyBox");
```

Comment: No, it has to be a control, not a form. And it must wait for the input. Or be able to wait until the button is pressed, because the function will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the box to reside on a form, you can just use a regular TextBox to get the inupt. Maybe eclose it in a GroupBox to give a "title", add a description label.

Lastly, and most importantly, add an "Update" Button to the GroupBox. Inside this button's Click handler, you can retrieve the value of the textbox with `string str = textbox.Text`.